# Match columns by regex and perform calculations using mutate in R dplyr?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, tidyverse

I am given a dataframe like this:

```
uncalibrated_gyro_x uncalibrated_gyro_y uncalibrated_gyro_z
1                   4                   7
2                   5                   8
3                   6                   9
```

sometimes I get these columns as `unc_gyr_x, unc_gyr_y, unc_gyr_z`

In any case I need to calculate the norm of this: `sqrt(x^2 + y^2 + z^2)`

These columns are part of a large dataframe with 50 columns.

How can I "tell" `mutate` using `regex` to use these columns that sometimes are given as `uncalibrated_gyro_x,y,z` and the other time as `unc_gyr_x,y,z`?

I know there is a function `matches` but it doesn't work for me in `mutate`.

Please advise.

Comment: Are these two sets of columns in the same dataframe and do they store different data? If so, you should probably start off with tidying your data so that you get one frame with uniform naming

Comment: What you want isn't very clear. Are the columns always containing a single number, ie only the header changes? (in which case you can use something like `mutate_at(vars(contains("gyr"), ~ (.)^2)` to get the squares). Or are the variables given as `uncalibrated_gyro_x,y,z` containing 3 values for x, y and z, respectively? (in which case the `separate()` function may be handy).

Comment: @meriops no if unc_gyr_x/y/z comes than uncalibrated_gyro_x/y/z doesn't appear. They contain the same data, their names can be different sometimes (2 sources of data (JSONs))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach would be to conditionally rename the variables so they're consistent and go from there:

```
df %>% 
   rename_at(vars(starts_with("uncalibrated_gyro_")),
             funs(sub("uncalibrated_gyro_", "unc_gyr_", .))) %>%
   mutate(myvar = sqrt(rowSums(select(.,starts_with("unc_gyr_"))^2)))
```